# How To get data firebase to list flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, graph

How to get Value data form my rtdb firebase to flutter in list linegarph

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database into a list in Flutter using a model. My list is returning as null when I do this.

this my data call

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

final List<Data> list = [];

  getData() async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('data').get();
    final map = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

    map.forEach((key, value) {
      final data = Data.fromMap(value);
      list.add(data);
      final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data.timeSTamp);
    });
  }

  class Data {

  final  dynamic sensorEc;
  final  dynamic sensorPh;
  final  dynamic sensorRtd;
  final  dynamic timeSTamp;
  final  dynamic humidity;
  final  dynamic temperature;

  Data({
    required this.sensorEc,
    required this.sensorPh,
    required this.sensorRtd,
    required this.timeSTamp,
    required this.humidity,
    required this.temperature,
  });

  factory Data.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return Data(
      sensorEc: map['EC'] ?? '',
      sensorPh: map['PH'] ?? '',
      sensorRtd: map['RTD'] ?? '',
      timeSTamp: map['TS']??'',
      humidity: map['humidity'] ?? '',
      temperature: map['temperature'] ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```

And this my widget call data graph

```
class GraphScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const GraphScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _GraphScreenState createState() => _GraphScreenState();
}

class _GraphScreenState extends State<GraphScreen> {
  late ChartSeriesController seriesController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfCartesianChart(
      zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
        enablePanning: true,
        enablePinching: true,
        enableDoubleTapZooming: true,
      ),
      plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
      primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
        dateFormat: DateFormat.yMMM(),
        interval: 1,
        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      ),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
        axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
        majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
      ),
      series: <ChartSeries<Data, DateTime>>[
        SplineAreaSeries<Data , DateTime>(
            dataSource: list,
            xValueMapper: (Data data, _) => data.timeSTamp,
            yValueMapper: (Data data, _) => data.sensorEc,
            onRendererCreated: (ChartSeriesController controller) {
              seriesController = controller;
            },
            color: Colors.transparent,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: Colors.blue),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

can you help me to get value in graph rtdb firebase flutter

this my rtdb
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6lmp.png)